# what is correct way to write this mysql join with google maps geocoding?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, google-maps

i have this script which works, but it takes a long time for the page and map to load when there are a lot of records in one of the tables.

one table is huge and the other small. `visitors_pb_list` is the small one.

is there a way to write the query so that it doesn't read every record in the 2nd table?

for example let's say table 1 has 10 records with landing_page number 500.
the other table could have 5 or 10 thousand or more records with that same landing_page number.

google has a limit as to the amount of queries that can be done.  can't go past like 2500, so i want this query to only ready the exact number of records based from table 1, and that many from table 2.  i don't want it to read 10 from table 1 and thousands from table 2.

can someone tell me most efficient way to do this query so geocoding doesn't get max limit error and so page and map loads fairly quickly?

the 3 lines that are commented out with google addresses, that is how the mysql query outputs lines from database using 2 tables.  only want to output the amount of records that table 1 has with a certain landing page number.  the other table houses the addresses, but has way to many records.

in the section with the query i have a few lines commented out.  i was trying different kinds of joins.  they all take forever to load and cause google to give max geocode query error.  i think i didn't try one of those, but anyway, i want to know which of those 4 query lines is the best, and if there is something better than all 4, what is it?

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var bounds;
var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: ''
});

//plot initial point using geocode instead of coordinates (works just fine)
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();

  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
  }
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '5th Avenue New York'}, function(results, status) { 
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

      markersArray.push(marker);
  }
  else{
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});

plotMarkers();
}

var locationsArray = [

//['Google Official','1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, USA'],
//['Google 1','112 S. Main St., Ann Arbor, USA'], 
//['Google 2','10 10th Street NE, Suite 600 USA'],

<?
//$emp_select="SELECT pb_list.*, visitors_pb_list.* FROM visitors_pb_list LEFT JOIN pb_list ON pb_list.landing_page=visitors_pb_list.landing_page WHERE visitors_pb_list.landing_page=".$pb_list_id."";
//$emp_select="SELECT pb_list.*, visitors_pb_list.* FROM visitors_pb_list INNER JOIN pb_list ON pb_list.landing_page=visitors_pb_list.landing_page WHERE visitors_pb_list.landing_page=".$pb_list_id."";
//$emp_select="SELECT pb_list.*, visitors_pb_list.* FROM pb_list LEFT JOIN visitors_pb_list ON pb_list.landing_page=visitors_pb_list.landing_page WHERE visitors_pb_list.landing_page=".$pb_list_id."";
$emp_select="SELECT pb_list.*, visitors_pb_list.* FROM pb_list INNER JOIN visitors_pb_list ON pb_list.landing_page=visitors_pb_list.landing_page WHERE visitors_pb_list.landing_page=".$pb_list_id."";
$emp_num=mysql_query($emp_select);
while($roww=mysql_fetch_array($emp_num)){ ?>

['Marker','<?php echo $roww['address'] ?>, <?php echo $roww['city'] ?>, <?php echo $roww['state'] ?>'],

<? } ?>

];

function plotMarkers(){
var i;
for(i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++){
    codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);
}
}

function codeAddresses(address){
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address[1]}, function(results, status) { 
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(address[0]);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

        markersArray.push(marker); 
    }
    else{
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline php, you could write plain js and query yout php backend asyncronically. Just pseudocoding here

```
function plotMarkers(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'geocoder.php',
        dataType:'json'
    }).done(function(locationsArray) {
       for(i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++){
           codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);
        }
    }); 
}
```

and in geocoder.php

```
$emp_select="SELECT pb_list.*, visitors_pb_list.* 
FROM pb_list 
INNER JOIN    visitors_pb_list ON pb_list.landing_page=visitors_pb_list.landing_page WHERE 
visitors_pb_list.landing_page=$pb_list_id";
$emp_num=mysql_query($emp_select);
$codeAddresses=array();
while($roww=mysql_fetch_assoc($emp_num)){
    $codeAddresses[]=$roww;
}
echo json_encode($codeAddresses);
```

PD: it isn't safe to write your queries that way, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections, but that's another subject entirely.

Comment: not working.  just spins and spins.  and in another page with a different landing page number with just 1 record in each table, it doesn't display the marker for that record.  you didn't say what to do with the locationsArray.  i deleted everything from inside of it and turned it into: var locationsArray = [];